# Python script execution from shared filesystem

Tags: python

I have 25 servers with a shared filesystem /automatons/ and my python script is residing under this directory. I need to run this script on all the servers at the same scheduled time. However, I can run this script only one server at a time.

If the script is running on server1 and i try to run the same on server2..it just returns the prompt.

Also, after doing above, script ceases to work on any of the servers. I have to make a copy of the script and then it works again.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: “However, I can run this script only one server at a time.” — Why? There’s no fundamental reason why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tendo`

```
from tendo import singleton
me = singleton.SingleInstance()
```

If the above doesn't work, try having a semaphore-like locking implementation by having a file that says whether the script is running or not. The file may have a boolean which is true when the script starts and false when it ends.

Comment: But that would prevent the script from running on multiple servers at same time... i need to run the script at same time on all servers